# Kendo grid pager issue after loading new data

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a problem with the Kendo grid pager misbehaving after loading new data into a grid. The grid is loaded when the page loads, configured as follows:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<MyModel>()
            .Name("Grid")
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                //snipped  
            })
            .Scrollable()
            .Sortable(sort => sort.Enabled(true))
            .Pageable(pager => pager.PageSizes(new int[] {10, 25, 50, 100}))
            .Events(events => events.DetailExpand("detailExpand").DetailCollapse("detailCollapse").DataBinding("onDataBinding"))
            .ClientDetailTemplateId("template")
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Ajax()
                .ServerOperation(false)
                .Sort(sort => sort.Add(Model.sort).Order(Model.Direction))
                .PageSize(Model.PageSize)
                .Events(events=>events.Error("onError"))
                .Read(read => read.Action("Summary", "Summary").Data("getFilterModel")))
                .Events(events => events.DataBound("dataBound"))
                .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
                .Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
              );
```

I have some controls on the page that serve as filters for the grid content. the getFilterModel function returns the values of those filters. When the user clicks the "Filter" button, I call read on the grid data source.

```
<button class="k-button" id="get" type="button" onclick="$('#Grid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();return false;">Filter</button>
```

This works OK on initial page load, and if I reload the grid with a number of rows <= the original number of rows. If I reload with a larger number of rows, the pager shows the correct count. But, if I try to click to advance to the next page, the pager reverts to showing 1 page only, and the grid shows empty.

Example: initial load contains 3 records, page size 25. Pager shows 1 page. OK. Change filters so the grid loads 42 rows. Pager shows 2 pages, set to page 1, and "1-25 of 42 items". Click to advance to page 2; grid shows no rows, pager shows 1 page and "26-25 of 25 items"

Does the pager need to be explicitly reset somehow?

This is an older version of Kendo MVC...DLL shows version 2013.3.1119.340.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, Kendo MVC and I outsmarted ourselves.

The `getFilterModel` function returned an object that contained both `Page` and `PageSize` properties, which get translated into query param names in the HTTP request. Those in turn become properties on the FilterModel object that is the model for the controller action. On the server side, the controller action calls the Kendo `ToDataSourceResult` extension method which apparently interpreted `Page` and `PageSize` and only returned the first page of the results.

Changing the names of those properties to `GridPage` and `GridPageSize` solved the problem. I had included them because I wanted to persist them as part of the grid state, but I may be better off finding another way to do that.